# Please explain a way of calculation of Lagrange multiplier in algorithm of low thrust transfer

Tags: astrodynamics, flight-control, calculation, low-thrust, algorithms

In David Vallado's book 'Fundamental of Astrodynamics and Applications', chapter 6.7. ("Continuous-Thrust Transfers") there is an algorithm #47: Low Thrust Transfer.  In this algorithm a part of code is not fully revealed, and instead of this there is remark: "Find λ (need to iterate)". I understood that under λ Vallado meant Lagrange multiplier λi from control hamiltonian. But for me is absolutely unclear, what should I iterate to calculate a value of this multiplier.

Comment: Is it mentioned in the section that $\lambda_i$ is a constant ? From [google books preview](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fundamentals_of_Astrodynamics_and_Applic/PJLlWzMBKjkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA382&printsec=frontcover&bsq=algorithm%2047), it appears that author is referring to techniques used in "*Bryson and Ho*" text book on optimal control.

Comment: Yes, λi is constant, but, for a single solution. I.e., in each exact case of calculation it will be different. For calculations I need it's value.
The book from link from Google Books looks like a kind of previous edition. I'm using 4-th edition of Vallado's book.
Yes, author mentioned Bryson and Ho textbook, written at 1987. But I didn't found it in internet, there is only Bryson and Ho book from 1975 (like this: http://e.guigon.free.fr/rsc/book/BrysonHo75.pdf), which looks like not that Vallado meant.

Comment: Typically one needs to iterate when a closed form solution to a problem doesn't exist. It would help a lot if you summarized Vallado's algorithm #47. (There are many at this site who are reluctant to shell out over \$300 US for a paperback.) Also note: Vallado's *Fundamental of Astrodynamics and Applications* is almost as widely criticized as *Numerical Recipes* for inaccuracies and lousy algorithms.